# Why does ReSharper claim "Expression is always true" in inlined function but not in method?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, resharper, rider

The code had no errors in Rider 2020.2 and before
I upgraded Rider to 2020.3.1 and also the ReSharper Command Line tools. Now I get this weird warning in a Xamarin C# project:

```
var controller = new UIActivityViewController(items.ToArray(), null);
controller.CompletionWithItemsHandler = (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) =>
{
    // here: Expression is always true
    if (error != null)
    {
        logger.Error("Error: {0}", error.Description);
    }
};
```

When I change the inlined handler to an method, the error goes away. What am I missing here?

```
private void CompletionWithItemsHandler(NSString activityType, bool completed, NSExtensionItem[] returnedItems, NSError error)
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        logger.Error("Error: {0}", error.Description);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there something up with your nullable reference types?

Comment: I am sorry to be so ignorant, but what does "my nullable reference types" mean (my C#-foo is limited)? UIActivityViewController is a Xamarin.iOS class and it did not change... and `error` clearly must be nullable for the callback to make sense

Comment: If you add a line `#nullable disable` above the function, does that do anything different?

Comment: @DavidG it doesn't. And I just checked the project settings, Nullable reference types are disabled.  ... maybe it's a bug in the new ReSharper when targeting Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: Is the `error` property marked with a NotNull attribute then? I don't have Xamarin installed right now so can't check.

Comment: I found the `UIActivityViewControllerCompletion` [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiactivityviewcontroller.completionwithitemshandler?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) delegate and it contains a `#nullable enable` when decompiled. The sdk docs does not mention nullability.
I wonder whether this is placed there by Rider's decompiler or was actually there in the compiled class? Either way this is clearly wrong, the `error` must be nullable, as specified in the apple docs (and as it is when running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the code is perfectly fine.

The developer of Xamarin.iOS have turned on Nullable reference types while not completely marking all nullable params correctly. It seems to be in there for quite a while, but the new version of Rider now also inspects library code that it previously apparently has not.